# Is the identity ($f(x)=x$) a linear dependence?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would say yes but as usual I can't be absolutely sure and I could have misunderstood. I understand linear dependence but can it also be as simple as $y=x$, $y=2x$ and likewise? Is similarly $y=x^3$ a cubic dependence or have I misunderstood? When I look in wikipedia and research the concept it's more about vectors than about functions.

Comment: You mean $y=x^3$?

Comment: @Nick Rosencrantz In what context did you find this problem? What do you mean with an equality being a linear dependence?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if I can say that y=x is a linear dependence, y=x² is a quadratic dependence and y=x³ is a cubic dependence and then I don't know next. Thanks for the elaborations.

Comment: There is something called "algebraic independence", which might be what you're looking for.  But your comment certainly adds a bit of clarity that doesn't seem to be in the question.  I thought you were talking about linear independence of $x^3$ and something else, rather than about "cubic independence" between $x$ and something else, expressed in a way that involves cubing $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am adding a good point here, although, I personally haven't heard or seen such that words (quadratic, cubic,...) in this area.

> A set of functions  $f_1(x),f_2(x),\ldots,f_n(x), x\in I$ is linearly dependent on $I$ iff the determinant below is identically zero on $I$:
>   $$ \det\left( \begin{array}{ccccc} \int_{a}^{b} f_1^2 \,dx& \int_{a}^{b} f_1f_2 \,dx&… &\int_{a}^{b}f_1f_n\,dx \\ \int_{a}^{b}f_2f_1\,dx & \int_{a}^{b}f_2^2\, dx &\ldots &\int_{a}^{b}f_2f_n\,dx \\ ⋮ & ⋮ & ⋮ &⋮ \\ \int_{a}^{b}f_nf_1\,dx & \int_{a}^{b}f_nf_2\,dx&\ldots &\int_{a}^{b}f_n^2\,dx \end{array} \right) $$

Comment: Nice! $\ddot\smile\quad$

Answer (score 2):

A linear dependence among an $m$-tuple $(f_1(x),\ldots,f_m(x))$ of functions is an $m$-tuple $(c_1,\ldots,c_m)\ne(0,\ldots,0)$ of scalars such that $c_1 f_1(x)+\cdots+c_m f_m(x)$ is the zero function (i.e. equal to $0$ regardless of what $x$ is).  Suppose we regard linear dependence as being expressed by the equality $\forall x\quad  c_1 f_1(x)+\cdots+c_m f_m(x)=0$.  If $y=x^3$, so that $y$ and $x^3$ are two different names of the same function, then the linear dependence of the pair $(y,x^3)$ could be considered to be expressed by that equality.  Or one could similarly say the pair $(x^3,x^3)$ is linearly dependent.  However, I wouldn't expect that necessarily to be how the written equality $y=x^3$ will be understood by someone who reads only that and nothing more.

Notice that in this context it matters that the things to which linear dependence or linear independence are attributed are tuples rather than sets or multisets.

Comment: BTW, notice that something like $a(c_1,\ldots,c_m)$, where $a$ is a nonzero scalar, expresses the _same_ linear dependence among the vectors involved.  I remember someone pointing out to me that the space of linear dependences among a tuple of vectors is for that reason actually a _projective space_, and it took all of probably two seconds for that to click in my mind.